# How to monitor jenkins build status from external applications

Tags: jenkins

We are developing a reporting application for my organization, which is aimed to monitor jenkins builds for specific jobs. I know there are API to get the status of the jobs and other information. But, it requires me to keep polling jenkins with these api requests. Would like to know, is there any other way like events thrown by jenkins so that my application can listen and do the needful ?

Answer (score -1):

You can "throw" whatever you want in your Jenkins build. Question is: what can you application "catch"?

You can make a POST or GET request at the end of the build to your application.
You can upload files to remote hosts.
You can update files on local host.
You can execute batch or shell scripts, remotely or locally.

So what **can** your application listen to?

Answer (score -1):

Got this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin, this solves my requirement